# Select between dates with count condition

Tags: mysql, time-series, aggregate-functions

I have table `user` with column `login_time`.

I want to select all the users that have logged in more than 10 times in a month.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT login_time, count(id) as loginCount FROM user 

WHERE login_time between DATE_SUB(login_time INTERVAL 1 month) AND login_time

GROUP BY id, MONTH(login_time) HAVING loginCount > 10;
```

Im not sure about my selection between dates.
How can I select with a month intervals avoiding double records.
For example if I have this values for `login_time`:

```
1. '2015-02-01 14:05:19'
2. '2015-01-21 14:05:19'
3. '2015-01-11 14:05:19'
```

Both 3 and 2 are within month range of 1. 
So will I get double records for that values?

Comment: Is the `GROUP BY id` intentional? It prevents grouping as a whole if only one table is concerned. Also `WHERE login_time BETWEEN x AND login_time` is essentially `WHERE login_time = login_time` which always matches.

Comment: I dont get it. Are you storing the number of times a user has logged in in a different table?

Comment: @karlingen yes, its in different table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the users who have logged in more than ten times in the month ending right now, do this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) times_logged_in,
       userid
  FROM user
 WHERE login_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*)> 10
```

To find the users who have logged in more than ten times in any calendar month in your table, do this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) times_logged_in,
       DATE(DATE_FORMAT(login_time, '%Y-%m-01')) month_beginning,
       userid
  FROM user
 GROUP BY user_id, DATE(DATE_FORMAT(login_time, '%Y-%m-01'))
HAVING COUNT(*)> 10
```

The trick here is the expression `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(login_time, '%Y-%m-01'))`, which converts any timestamp to the first day of the month in which it occurs.

Your question mentioned this `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE login_time between DATE_SUB(login_time INTERVAL 1 month) AND login_time
```

This doesn't do anything interesting because it always comes back true. Each given `login_time` always falls in the interval you specified.

**Edit**: You can `GROUP BY MONTH(dt)` if you want. But the way I have shown it automatically accounts for years as well as months, so in my opinion it's much better for accurate reporting.

**Another edit**:  This formula yields the preceding Sunday for any given date or timestamp item.

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(login_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(login_time) -1, 7))
```

If Monday is the first day of the week in your jurisdiction, change the `-1` to `-2`.   Grouping by this function is superior to doing `GROUP BY WEEK(login_time)` because `WEEK()` does odd things at the beginnings and ends of calendar years.

This is all written up in more detail here: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Comment: Thanks. I understand that my where was bad. Can I use in `GROUP BY` this: `MONTH(login_time )` instead of `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(login_time, '%Y-%m-01'))`

Comment: How I can make the group by for weeks?